jQuery UI datepicker month select box opens and closes immediately inside Bootstrap 5.3.3 modal for firefox browser
I've encountered a conflict between Bootstrap's modal and jQuery UI datepicker in firefox browser where I can't use the month select box because something closes it immediately after being open.
Steps to reproduce:
click button "Launch demo modal"
click on the input box inside to activate the datepicker
click on the select box the change the month and you'll see it closes immediately

Here is an example:
https://codepen.io/ioknuatk-the-typescripter/pen/OJeXXeN

HTML 5 has a month type of INPUT elements (as well as several over date/time types). Would you be open to using this? The disadvantage is in having to code in this change. The advantage is in possibly eliminating JQuery UI from your stack which could have performance benefits

For me, the month did not change. I would eliminate modal class and see if you can use calendar widget without it. Then, look for another modal feature if possible.
